# Sort query according to GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
SELECT plague, fecha, FORMAT(((cuadrantes_infectados * 100) / total_cuadrantes),3) AS percentage
FROM (
            SELECT pr_plagues.plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) AS fecha,
                        (SELECT COUNT(pr_production_units_details.id)
                         FROM pr_production_units_details
                         INNER JOIN pr_grouper_details ON pr_grouper_details.id = pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail
                         WHERE pr_production_units_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_grouper_details.id_land = 1
                         AND pr_grouper_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1) * (SELECT value FROM cf_config WHERE parameter = 'PLANTHEALTH_QUADRANTS' AND id_tenant = 1) AS total_cuadrantes,
                         COUNT(ph_planthealth_detail.quadrant) AS cuadrantes_infectados
            FROM ph_planthealth
            INNER JOIN ph_planthealth_detail ON ph_planthealth_detail.id_planthealth = ph_planthealth.id
            INNER JOIN pr_plagues ON pr_plagues.id = ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague
            WHERE YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) BETWEEN YEARWEEK('2017-06-01') AND YEARWEEK('2017-06-10')
            AND ph_planthealth.status = 200
            AND ph_planthealth.id_tenant = 1
            AND ph_planthealth.id_land = 1
            GROUP BY ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date)
) AS s
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

which gives me the following result:

```
----------------------------------------
   plague   |    fecha  |   percentage 
----------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201723  |    9.911      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201722  |    6.728      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201722  |    4.727      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201723  |    4.358      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201723  |    4.023      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201722  |    2.903      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201722  |    2.760      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201723  |    10.266    
---------------------------------------
```

What I want is to order **plague** from the highest **percentage** to the lowest, according to the value of the last week is 201723, but is grouped with the week 201722

So I want the following result:

```
   plague   |    fecha  |   percentage 
----------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201723  |    10.266      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA2   |   201722  |    4.727      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201723  |    9.911      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA1   |   201722  |    6.728      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201723  |    4.358      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA3   |   201722  |    2.760      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201723  |    4.023      
---------------------------------------
   PLAGA4   |   201722  |    2.903     
---------------------------------------
```

I have researched but I have not been able to group it and organize it that way, I hope I can help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CAST` to `NUMERIC/DECIMAL` to get number sort instead of text sort:

```
SELECT plague, fecha, FORMAT(((cuadrantes_infectados * 100) / total_cuadrantes),3) AS percentage
FROM (
            SELECT pr_plagues.plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) AS fecha,
                        (SELECT COUNT(pr_production_units_details.id)
                         FROM pr_production_units_details
                         INNER JOIN pr_grouper_details ON pr_grouper_details.id = pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail
                         WHERE pr_production_units_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_grouper_details.id_land = 1
                         AND pr_grouper_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1) * (SELECT value FROM cf_config WHERE parameter = 'PLANTHEALTH_QUADRANTS' AND id_tenant = 1) AS total_cuadrantes,
                         COUNT(ph_planthealth_detail.quadrant) AS cuadrantes_infectados
            FROM ph_planthealth
            INNER JOIN ph_planthealth_detail ON ph_planthealth_detail.id_planthealth = ph_planthealth.id
            INNER JOIN pr_plagues ON pr_plagues.id = ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague
            WHERE YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) BETWEEN YEARWEEK('2017-06-01') AND YEARWEEK('2017-06-10')
            AND ph_planthealth.status = 200
            AND ph_planthealth.id_tenant = 1
            AND ph_planthealth.id_land = 1
            GROUP BY ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date)
) AS s
ORDER BY CAST(percentage AS NUMERIC(38,4)) DESC;
```

---

Or even better, do not use `FORMAT` at all:

```
SELECT plague, fecha, CAST(((cuadrantes_infectados * 100) / total_cuadrantes) AS NUMERIC(38,3)) AS percentage
FROM (
            SELECT pr_plagues.plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) AS fecha,
                        (SELECT COUNT(pr_production_units_details.id)
                         FROM pr_production_units_details
                         INNER JOIN pr_grouper_details ON pr_grouper_details.id = pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail
                         WHERE pr_production_units_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_grouper_details.id_land = 1
                         AND pr_grouper_details.status = 100
                         AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1) * (SELECT value FROM cf_config WHERE parameter = 'PLANTHEALTH_QUADRANTS' AND id_tenant = 1) AS total_cuadrantes,
                         COUNT(ph_planthealth_detail.quadrant) AS cuadrantes_infectados
            FROM ph_planthealth
            INNER JOIN ph_planthealth_detail ON ph_planthealth_detail.id_planthealth = ph_planthealth.id
            INNER JOIN pr_plagues ON pr_plagues.id = ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague
            WHERE YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date) BETWEEN YEARWEEK('2017-06-01') AND YEARWEEK('2017-06-10')
            AND ph_planthealth.status = 200
            AND ph_planthealth.id_tenant = 1
            AND ph_planthealth.id_land = 1
            GROUP BY ph_planthealth_detail.id_plague, YEARWEEK(ph_planthealth.date)
) AS s
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```